# how to make the previous otp code expired in Google2FA used Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, google-2fa

I have code OTP for verification.

I have problem when i verification code OTP, previous code OTP its true, it should be wrong.

Example :

OTP code 1: 325 620 (previous OTP code) --> when I input this code it's already wrong

OTP code 2: 412 650 (previous OTP code) --> when entering this code it still reads
correctly, it should be wrong

OTP code 3: 441 225 (current OTP code) -> this is correct, this code also fits in the input

So the previous OTP code is the same as now, reads correctly

My Blade

```
<div class="form-group">
    @if($errors->any())
        <b style="color: red">{{$errors->first()}}</b><br>
    @endif
    <label for="one_time_password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Masukkan Kode OTP</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="one_time_password" type="number" class="form-control text-center" name="one_time_password" minLength="6" maxLength="6" required autofocus>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so I hope you solved it for yourself!  But I just started using & configuring this package, so I wanted to share.

The 'window' of the OTP code sounds like what you're looking for. But, other settings & notes are available in the package configuration file, so I would recommend checking those out (config/google2fa.php).

Some of the configuration is self-documenting, but there aren't many examples of the use of the window configuration option in the README.  This article helped me understand what it was trying to do: https://morioh.com/p/225528ad5ce3

#### One Time Password Window.

- Defines how long an OTP will work, or how many cycles it will last. A key has a 30-second cycle.
- Value of `1` => Keys will be valid for 60 seconds

  - `'window' => 1,`
- So a window of `1` would mean keys from the previous minute and next minute are still valid (approximately always at least 2 previous codes [at 2 codes per minute]).